# Screen background changing when phone is tilted horizontal

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In the android app I am developing I have given the background of one color. When the phone is tilted horizontal the screen background changes to a lighter version of the previous color?
What to do, to avoid this?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#228b22"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you've coded the color change into your app then its not happening in the program. What's more likely is that your device has a low quality LCD that has limited viewing angles.